# Google analytics for track user log in time and log out time

Tags: google-analytics, vuejs2

Hi we have a project for a travel guide mobile app. I developed the front-end admin panel. Our client wants to get the user logs (Simply who logs at what time) for the admin panel.

The admin panel developed using vue js. So I use [Vue analytics plug-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zDgV.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zDgV.png): https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics for that.

Since I want to track only the user logs (login and logout) I add to methods to the code like this.

**onLogOut**

```
this.$ga.event("user logs", "log out", user_name, 5)
```

**onLogIn**

```
this.$ga.event("user logs", "log in", user_name, 2);
```

I am quite new to GA. When I go to **real time -> events** it looks like this

[image]

But what I want is a report like this

```
Category    | Action  | Label
__________________________________________________________
User logs   | log in  | Patrick star - 2019/01/31 10.00 AM
User logs   | log in  | Homer jay    - 2019/01/31 10.19 AM
User logs   | log in  | Scooby doo   - 2019/01/31 11.31 AM
User logs   | log out | Patrick star - 2019/01/31 11.45 AM
User logs   | log out | Scooby doo   - 2019/01/31 10.00 AM
```

How could I generate this kind of report using google analytics.

Comment: As a side note, remember that per Google's terms of service you are not allowed to store personally identifiable data, so make sure that "user_name" is something that cannot be resolved by any third party into an actual person's name.

Answer (score 0):

In Analytics, navigate to Behaviour > Events > Top Events report. 
You may click through report rows to get details specific group of events. Use tabs or secondary dimensions to get the desired layout.
[image]